# Swift flatMap chain unwrap

Tags: swift, combine

Have somebody faced the issue working with such flatMap chain (or even longer) when compiler went to infinite loop.

```
let what = Future<String, Error>.init { (promise) in
    promise(.success("123"))
}
.flatMap { (inStr) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> in
    Future<Int, Error>.init { (promise) in
        promise(.success(Int(inStr)!))
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
} 
.flatMap { (inInt) -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> in
    Just(String(inInt))
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

The type of Publisher Output and Failure are terrible!
[image]

I have flatMap chain with 7 steps and you can imagine the actual type.
Maybe somebody knows how to handle this correctly?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: So this code doesn't compile for you? It runs fine for me in a playground using Xcode 11.5 (and hence Swift 5.1). Calling `eraseToAnyPublisher` in the middle of the chain would most probably help the compiler resolve the types.

Comment: That's why `some Type` feature was added along with `Combine` library. All return types are wild like that there.

Comment: As a rule, `some Type` isn't useful for Publishers. Its primary use currently is for SwiftUI. Publishers generally need to be erased down to AnyPublisher (at the point of returning them). `some` and `AnyPublisher` solve different kinds of problems.

Comment: Semi off topic: `Future<Int, Error>.init {` vs. `Future<Int, Error> {` -- Swift have regular constructors you know, you don't _have_ to call `.init`. And the return type is implied in your closures, so you can simplify your own code a lot before complaining about the Combine type output ;-)

Comment: @DávidPásztor Code compiling well. Problem in time of compiling. With 7 flat maps it took a minute from my i9 mac

Answer (score 2):

This is really just a mirage. It's exactly equivalent to `AnyPublisher<String, Error>`:

```
let what: AnyPublisher<String, Error> = Future<String, Error>() { (promise) in
...
```

The mirage comes about because of associated types. The final type is `Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<String, Error>, Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<Int, Error>, Future<String, Error>>>`, and from that the `AnyPublisher` extracts `Output` and `Error`. A little bit of unwinding should make it clear that these are just elaborate type aliases for exactly `String` and `Error`. Hopefully as Combine becomes more common, the tools will become better at simplifying these type alias in diagnostics. The compiler already does that a lot. It just needs to be a little smarter in these cases. But using an explicit type on the variable (or on the return value of a function), you can get the spelling you want.

---

Per your comment, that the problem is compile time, that's a common problem with chaining in Swift. It's not Combine-specific and has little to do with the complexity of the types. The most common version of this is having a lot of terms strung together with `+` (though the Swift team has done a lot of work to improve that one). The solution (as elsewhere) is to break up the expression.

```
let what = Future<String, Error>.init { (promise) in
    promise(.success("123"))
}

let what1 = what
    .flatMap { (inStr) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> in
        Future<Int, Error>.init { (promise) in
            promise(.success(Int(inStr)!))
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

let what2 = what1 
    .flatMap { (inInt) -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> in
        Just(String(inInt))
            .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

You don't have to break it up into individual steps like this of course. But at various points, you'll want to break up the expression. Proving that the types are correct can be an exponential-time problem. The way you deal with exponential-time problems is to make sure that "n" is small.

Comment: We have to agree to disagree. See my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/tricksandtips.html for an opposed view. :)

Comment: @matt Actually, I don't think we disagree. It turns out the mirage I discuss exists both ways, so my "cleanup" wasn't necessary. Not sure which way I prefer, but to this specific question, the results are identical. Editing. (I thought the extra anypublishers would cause actual barriers that they don't.)

Comment: I completely understand that result type is AnyPublisher<String,Error> but the problem is in actual compiler it self and in time that it spend to compile one line of code change. I have 7 flat maps in sequence and the me code i9 was stuck for 1 minute on build

Comment: That's not related to the complexity of the types per-se. It's the complexity of the expression (this has been a major problem in Swift long before Combine). The solution to that is breaking up the expression into sub-expressions, and assign each to a variable.